# g.Init(); cannot find symbol

Tags: java

So I am getting this error when I try to run this short piece of code. The error is :

cannot find symbol

```
  g.Init();
      ^
  symbol:   method Init()
  location: variable g of type Game

  1 error
```

Ok so I initially thought that I did not have the proper imports so I inserted  `import java.util.*;` but i still got the same error. Do I have to define the init function for it to run? Or is they some other import that i need to call. I think the problem lies more with the `init();` but i could be wrong. Therefore, if anyone can offer me a tip or help me out on this I would appreciate it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Game {


   public static void main( String[] args ) {

    System.out.println( "Hello world!" );
     Game g = new Game();
     g.Init();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you define an object, you must define its behavior by supplying methods. In java, you have a special method which is called a constructor, that is called when you initialize the object (new...). Init is not a function that Java know unless you define it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the problem is that your Game class does not have an Init() function defined. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with Init(), but you don't actually need it to run your program.

```
public class Game {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {

   System.out.println( "Hello world!" );

  }
}
```

Or

```
public class Game {


   public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Game g = new Game();
    g.Init();
  }

  public void Init()
  {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
  }
}
```

Should work, it depends on how you want to structure your program.

Comment: Wow thanks you for helping its nice to know i was close in getting it

Answer (score 0):

For above program, you should define one method with the name Init(), and should define the functioanilty inside that, As answered by aoi222.

And main thing no need to import any predefined packages untill required.

Thanks,
@rs